# Java: How to round to a decimal point without saving to memory

Tags: java, math

Hey guys I have a project for my programming class to make a quadratic calcuator, and it works great however all my outputs need to be rounded to 5 decimal places. I can easily do that with a saved variable by using %.5f, but my professor only wants us to save something to a variable if we are using it more than once. As you can see in my code alot of the solutions like the x-intercepts etc. are used only once so I am not allowed to save them. Is there a way to force a math string to output numbers such as 3.00000? I have searched, but without knowing the technical terms to search with it is very hard to get an answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ps.print("Enter the coefficient of the quadratic term -> ");
    double coefficientQuad = in.nextInt();
    ps.print("Enter the coefficient of the linear term -> ");
    double coefficientLin = in.nextInt();
    ps.print("Enter the coefficient of the constant term -> ");
    double coefficientCon = in.nextInt();
    ps.println();
    ps.printf("For the quadratic equation %.5fx^2 + %.5fx + %.5f = 0\n", coefficientQuad, coefficientLin, coefficientCon);
    ps.println();
    double discriminant = Math.pow(coefficientLin, 2) - 4 * coefficientQuad * coefficientCon;
    ps.printf("Discriminant: %.5f\n", discriminant);
    ps.println("Roots: x = {" + (-coefficientLin + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / 2 * coefficientQuad + "," + (-coefficientLin - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / 2 * coefficientQuad + "}");
    double axisOfSymmetry = (-coefficientLin / 2 * coefficientQuad);
    ps.printf("Axis of Symmetry: x = %.5f\n", axisOfSymmetry);
    ps.printf("Vertex: (%.5f, " + (-Math.pow(coefficientLin, 2) / 4 * coefficientQuad + coefficientCon) + ")\n", axisOfSymmetry);
    ps.println("x-intercepts: (" + (-coefficientLin + Math.sqrt(discriminant) / 2 * coefficientQuad) + ", 0.00000) and (" + (-coefficientLin - Math.sqrt(discriminant) / 2 * coefficientQuad) + ", 0.00000)");
    ps.printf("y-intercept: (0.00000, %.5f)", coefficientCon);
```

Comment: If you need to print a value and also do something else with it, then that's using it at least twice.  If you need only to print it, then you do not need to pass it to `PrintStream.printf()` indirectly via a variable; you can just use whatever expression produces the value as the `printf()` argument, directly.

Comment: You're mixing values into the format string using string concatenation. **DON'T**. Change `printf("Vertex: (%.5f, " + (...) + ")\n", axisOfSymmetry)` to `printf("Vertex: (%.5f, %.5f)%n", axisOfSymmetry, (...))`. Same for this: Change `println("x-intercepts: (" + (...) + ", 0.00000) and (" + (...) + ", 0.00000)")` to `printf("x-intercepts: (%.5f, 0.00000) and (%.5f, 0.00000)%n", (...), (...))`. When using `printf()`, it is very rare for the format string (the first parameter) to be anything other than a string literal.

Comment: Why are you doing stuff like `double coefficientQuad = in.nextInt()`?  While it technically works, it is prone to errors.  `Scanner` has a `nextDouble()` method which won't crash if you give it input like 1.5.

Comment: Frankly, your professor has made a stupid rule if he says you can't create a variable you will only use once.  It has the potential to make real-world code unreadable if there are complex statements.  Even this I would say is difficult to read because you have multiple complex statements in one line.